# How can the NSI45020T1G claim to "turn on immediately"?

Tags: led, mosfet-driver, constant-current

The [On Semi NSI45020T1G](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nsi45020-d.pdf), a simple two-terminal inline current regulator, claims in at least two places that it "turns on immediately". However,

1. it cites a capacitance between 2.5 and 2.7 pF. If that capacitance is modelled in parallel with the device, won't there be a (brief) charge-up period where the current surges beyond 20 mA?
2. Figure 5:

[image: Current regulation vs. time]

shows that it might not stabilise for over ten seconds!

This concerns me because I'm considering whether to include this in the arm of a PWM-dimmed LED driver:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSN7Px.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will the current source be too slow, or introduce unwanted transients during PWM? The 7-segment display claims an absolute max of 25 mA and doesn't distinguish between peak and continuous.

Comment: I suspect you're overthinking this.

Comment: @Hearth I'd be thrilled if the answer is simpler; I'm all ears

Comment: maybe it means `no enable signal required`

Comment: Figure 5 shows long-term settling, possibly due to thermal drift. And the current does indeed turn on 'immediately' (at time = 0) on the graph. It shows no rise time at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any guaranteed numbers related to turn-on speed, however-

A more sensible answer might be implied by the phrase:

> The LEDs and the CCR switch extremely fast, less than 100 nanoseconds.

This is important if you want to PWM the LED + regulator chain.

The small current change in the graph is thermal in nature and will hardly be perceptible visually.

Comment: Ok; so long as I use a PWM period "significantly longer than 100 ns" I should be OK, in that case.

Comment: If the PWM time resolution is greater than 100ns then there will be little effect, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Phrases like, "turns on immediately", comes from marketing not from engineers.

Engineers use words like, current regulates to within 5% within 7 seconds.

If a claim is made with words and doesn't include numeric values, beware. Just for a broad description marketeers use simpler phrases.